# How to use Guava to cache HTTP responses? (without thread being blocked)

Tags: java, retrofit, guava, rx-java2, okhttp

So I am trying to cache HTTP responses (using OkHtttp + retrofit, rxjava for multithreading) using Guava cache. It currently looks something like:

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://blablabla.com")
            .client(client)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    apiClient = retrofit.create(Api.class);

    CacheLoader<Integer, HttpResponse> cacheLoader = new CacheLoader<Integer, HttpResponse>() {
        @Override
        public Response load( Integer key ) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
            return apiClient.getHttpResponse(key)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .blockingFirst();
        }
    };

    responseCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .concurrencyLevel(8)
            .maximumSize( 10 )
            .build(cacheLoader);
```

The apiClient returns Observable, and it is subscribed within the CacheLoader's load method. I have also set `concurrencyLevel(8)` but it doesn't seem to allow 'loading' and 'reading' at the same time.

I think the `blockingFirst()` call probably block the thread so I can't make concurrent requests from the cache i.e. whenever cache is loading a new http response, cache can't be read.

I don't know how to make it asynchronous, any help is appreciated :)

Comment: is there any reason you are not using the [caching](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#response-caching) provided by OkHttp?

Comment: I believe Okhttp's cache is saved on disk, I am trying to use an in-memory cache..

Answer (score 0):

Using Guava, you can still make asynchronous non-blocking calls and cache HTTP responses, but you will have to manually call cache.put() after the HTTP response is received. So you can define your LoadingCache like the below.

```
private LoadingCache<String, ServerResponse> cache =
    CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .maximumSize(50)
        .expireAfterWrite(24, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        .build(
            new CacheLoader<String, ServerResponse>() {
                public ServerResponse load(String id) {
                    return null; // or empty ServerResponse
                }
            });
```

And in your in your calling method:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://blablabla.com")
        .client(client)
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

apiClient = retrofit.create(Api.class);

try {
    ServerResponse cachedResponse = cache.get(someUniqueKey);
    if (cachedResponse != null) {
        // return cachedResponse here
        return;
    }
    doNormalHttpRequest()
} catch (ExecutionException | CacheLoader.InvalidCacheLoadException e) {
    doNormalHttpRequest();
}

void doNormalHttpRequest() {
    apiClient.request(body).enqueue(
        new retrofit2.Callback<ServerResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call,
                Response<ServerResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    cache.put(someUniqueKey, response.body();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable {}
    });
}
```

As an added bonus, this can cache POST requests as well since retrofit only caches GET requests using OkHttp's caching implementation.